# Javascript - click event on table rows to change HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html-table, event-handling

I'm still new to JavaScript, so apologies if any of this is unclear:

I have dynamically created a table in JS and added a click handler to each row, which is working fine. But I want that click to change some elements in a separate container I have got in the HTML - i.e. if you click on the 1st row of the table, then that will change the text to show more details about what is in that row.

Where I'm struggling is how to get it so that that clicking on each row will change it to the details for that row (i.e. click on row 2 and it changes to the details for row 2, click on row 5 and it changes to the details for row 5 etc.).

I have a function set up - loadDetails(num), where the parameter num should be the number of the row (e.g. if I call loadDetails(0) it will return the details for the 1st row). So basically I want to create something so that for each row it will call this function with the correct number as the parameter. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

```
function myFunction() {

    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    //code in here?
    //then call the loadDetails() function?  
    }

    //or call the loadDetails() function here?  

}
```

Edit: here is the code for creating the table - it is basically creating a table with three columns and getting its data from a JSON array (tableOne). So the third line is where I'm struggling - I'm not sure how to assign the id for the tr so that it is unique each time it loops through?

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableOne.length; i++) { 
    var row1 = document.createElement("tr");
    row1.id = "row" + i;
    row1.addEventListener("click", loadSelected, false);
    var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    cell1.innerHTML = tableOne[i].firstName;
    var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
    cell2.innerHTML = tableOne[i].lastName;
    var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
    cell3.innerHTML = tableOne[i].age;

    row1.appendChild(cell1);
    row1.appendChild(cell2);
    row1.appendChild(cell3);

    tbody.appendChild(row1);
    table.appendChild(row1);
}
```

Comment: What format are the details in? For example, is it a `<td>..</td><td>...</td>` string that could theoretically be put inside a `<tr>`? (if not, you'll have to figure out how to format it the way you want first)

Comment: @CertainPerformance The details in the table itself are in a '<td>', however the additional details that I want to populate in the separate div is a mix of headings and paragraphs. I think I have that part sorted and it is populating what I want when I test it out just using a random number i.e. loadDetails(0). So I think all I need to work out is how to code it so that for each different row that is clicked, it is passing in the number of the clicked row to the function. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a method of tracking each row in a unique manner.Something like id field of the database table row will help for this.
So when you render your table then you could add this value to each row.

How you render your `<tr>`

```
<tr id="row1" onClick="myFunction"> Row 01 </tr>
<tr id="row2" onClick="myFunction"> Row 02 </tr>
<tr id="row3" onClick="myFunction"> Row 03 </tr>
```

Then you can access the `id` as follows from your function

```
function myFunction(e) {
  let id = e.target.id; 
  if(id) {
     loadDetails(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I like that approach - I'm just not sure how I go about assigning a unique ID to each row when I dynamically create the table:                                        
       `for (var i = 0; i < tableOne.length; i++) { 
        var row1 = document.createElement("tr");
        row1.id = ????` //what do I need to assign the id of the row as to make it unique for each time it loops through?

Comment: You have to assign this while you are generating the table(i would like to see that code)You could just use your `num` value for this or some incremental value.

Comment: I have added the code that I have used to generate the table - it's the third line where I think I want to assign the id?

Comment: you could just simply use the tr id you are assigning.`event.target.id` will return that id.i have updated my answer with that

Answer (score 1):

You could use rowIndex to get the index of the clicked row

```
row.addEventListener("click", myfunction, false);
```

In your function, you can use this.rowIndex to get the index of the clicked row

```
function myfunction(e) {
  loadDetails(this.rowIndex)
}
```